# Is there example data for the Apache Derby SAMP schema?

Tags: derby

The Apache Derby documentation makes many references to the "SAMP" schema.

Does Derby come with example data for this schema ?

For example the Derby Reference Manual refers to the SAMP schema many times (http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's an example of the documentation you're reading?

The [most recent Derby documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/index.html) uses the 'toursdb' database, I thought.

You can load the toursdb data here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/twwdactivity1_Setup.html and http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/twwdactivity1.html

Comment: For example the Derby Reference Manual (http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html). It would be nice to follow through the examples with actual working commands but toursdb does not appear to contain a SAMP schema.